# drush migrate-upgrade "[debug] key_value table not found. Database may be empty."

Tags: 8, drush, migrations, composer

I am trying to migrate a D7 site to D8 following the steps found [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/upgrade/upgrade-using-drush) .

Once I can manage it and make sure I have all the PHP components, Drupal modules and etc. I have 4 sites to update, and one that I suspect is going to be very difficult.

I installed and used Composer to make a Drupal 8 site off my /home directory with the intent to move the files over the existing website. Plus it seems the migrate-upgrade needs to reference the D7 site via http.

When I run the following command to migrate the old (D7) site to this new D8 site it fails.

```
drush migrate-upgrade --legacy-db-url=mysql://user:password@server/db  
--legacy-root=http://example.com --configure only
```

with the following parameters for my specific environment

- user = user the site uses to connect to the database
- password
- server = localhost
- db = database name
- http://example.com = URL for the website

When it fails, it cites **[debug] key_value table not found. Database may be empty. [0.1 sec, 9.59 MB]** and when I check the MySQL database I find there is no table name ***key_value***.

I could create the table, if I know the requirements for the table (field names, field type, sizes, PK/FK, etc.).  Or is there some other means to create this table.

Previously I did everything manually.
I thought since the update steps found in this [Guide](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/upgrade-drupal-7-to-drupal-8/) had the overall process involve making a D8 site and migrating the data over that I should use Composer and/or Drush.
This is my first time getting Composer and Drush working for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

---

I get the following output when I run the whole **drush migrate-upgrade** command:

> Drush Launcher Version: 0.6.0
>   ROOT: /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne
>   DRUSH VERSION: 9
>   DRUPAL ROOT: /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne
>   COMPOSER ROOT: /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne
>   VENDOR ROOT: /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne/vendor
>    [preflight] Config paths: /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne/vendor/drush/drush/drush.yml
>    [preflight] Alias paths: /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne/drush/sites,/home/akwashnak/drush/sites
>    [preflight] Commandfile search paths: /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne/vendor/drush/drush/src
>    [debug] Bootstrap further to find migrate-upgrade [0.08 sec, 8.02 MB]
>    [debug] Trying to bootstrap as far as we can [0.08 sec, 8.02 MB]
>    [debug] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalRoot() [0.08 sec, 8.02 MB]
>    [debug] Change working directory to /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne [0.08 sec, 8.02 MB]
>    [debug] Initialized Drupal 8.7.9 root directory at /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne [0.08 sec, 8.15 MB]
>    [debug] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalSite() [0.09 sec, 8.5 MB]
>    [debug] Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.09 sec, 8.67 MB]
>    [debug] Drush bootstrap phase: bootstrapDrupalConfiguration() [0.09 sec, 8.67 MB]
>    [debug] Add service modifier [0.1 sec, 9.17 MB]
>    **[debug] key_value table not found. Database may be empty. [0.1 sec, 9.59 MB]** 
>    [debug] Bootstrap phase bootstrapDrupalDatabase() failed to validate; continuing at bootstrapDrupalConfiguration() [0.1 sec, 9.59 MB]
>    [debug] Done with bootstrap max in Application::find(): trying to find migrate-upgrade again. [0.1 sec, 9.59 MB]
>
> In Application.php line 239:
>
> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>     Command migrate-upgrade was not found. Drush was unable to query the database. As a result, many commands are unavailable. Re-run your command with --de
>     bug to see relevant log messages.
>
> Exception trace:
>     at /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne/vendor/drush/drush/src/Application.php:239
>    Drush\Application->bootstrapAndFind() at /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne/vendor/drush/drush/src/Application.php:192
>    Drush\Application->find() at /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:236
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:148
>    Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:118
>    Drush\Runtime\Runtime->doRun() at /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne/vendor/drush/drush/src/Runtime/Runtime.php:49
>    Drush\Runtime\Runtime->run() at /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:72
>    require() at /home/akwashnak/ctdollarsandsesne/vendor/drush/drush/includes/preflight.inc:18
>    drush_main() at phar:///usr/local/bin/drush/bin/drush.php:141
>    require() at /usr/local/bin/drush:10

Answer (score 2):

"Drush was unable to query the database" tells you that your issue isn't a missing table, but a configuration issue.

You do need to start with an empty but working D8 site before you try running the migration. I'm thinking you didn't initialize your site after downloading the code with composer?

To be clearer: composer is a tool for managing code, not for managing the site as a whole. After using composer to download the code, you still need to create your database and use drush or the web interface to actually "set up" your site. Only at that point can drush migrate can start doing its thing.

Comment: I had followed the instructions to install from Composer

Comment: (sorry, timed out) I had followed the instructions to install from Composer outlined in drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#composer-from-scratch which starts with `composer init`, then installs composer tools before running `composer require drupal/core`.  I did the initial `composer init` and don't see anything for initializing the site.

Comment: Sounds like you've got as far as step 2 of https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/install - you still need steps 3 & 5 to install the website (maybe step 4 too if you want to host the site)

Comment: Once the site is installed you'll also need to install the migrate/migrate plus modules to make the drush commands available

Comment: So I need to create a new database and have the new site somewhere accessible by Apache?  Make it a full independent site before migrating the data over from the D7 site?

Comment: That is correct.